Can I multiply both sides of an equation with $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x}$?
Can I multiply both sides of an equation with $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{x}$?
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-(bx + c)) = \lim_{x \to \infty}0$$
$$\lim_{x->\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)- bx ) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot\lim_{x \to \infty}c.$$
Can I do this, and why does it work? Isn't multiplying both sides with $0$ losing data?
$$\lim_{x->\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}- \frac{bx}{x}\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{c}{x}\right)$$
$$\lim_{x->\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}- \frac{bx}{x}\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{c}{x}\right)$$
$$\lim_{x \to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right) = \lim_{x \to\infty}\left(\frac{bx}{x}\right)$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right) = b.$$
Find $b$.
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(f(x)-bx\right) = c.$$
Find $c$.


It may help to use \to for $\to$, surround formulas with $/$$, and use braces \lim_{x\to\infty} for $\lim_{x\to\infty}$

This is unreadable. Please [edit] the question using mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

OP: I'll do one equation, and you can do the rest, OK?

You multiply FIRST, and THEN you take the limit.
When you are doing something like this, if you guess the limit is a real number $L\in\mathbb{R}$ then you should use the definition of limits. Lets suppose that $g(x)$ results from the manipulations of your $f(x)$ evaluated at arbitrary variables, multiplying and substracting whatever, then you use the definition:

For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $N=N(\varepsilon)>1$ such that FOR ALL $x>N$, $|g(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Then you apply this for the SPECIFIC function $f(x)$, because the result depends heavily on what function are we talking about.
Remember: you first multiply by $1/x$, do the algebraic manipulations FOR ANY $x\neq 0$, and then you apply the limit.
